# How to listen mysql database changes in Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, google-cloud-messaging, listener

I have an android application and I use a mysql database. I'm connecting to db via my PHP script. I want to make a listener for mysql database. It will listen updating and inserting events on mysql db and I will be informed. How can I carry out this event on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have a Updates table that holds the primary key of the table that you want to observe, and a trigger which listens for updates on table you like and enters the id of that updated entry to the Updates table.

you will have a RESTful webservice which will query the Updates table and will provide the change.

and on android all you need to do is connect that webservice via basic GET request by the help of 'Volley' i guess.

thats the scenario that came to my mind when i read your question.

Comment: Hocam türkçe yazabilir misin rica etsem :-)

Comment: Ok işaretledim gönderebilir misin txt linkini? Detaylı konuşabilir miyiz ayrıca bu konuyu faceden falan?